# Producer/consumer pattern via mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, producer-consumer

I have 2 processes that act as a producer/consumer via a table.
One process does **only** INSERT into the table while the other process does a **SELECT** for new records and an **UPDATE** of these records when it finishes to mark them as finished.
This keeps happening constantly.
As far as I can see there is no need for any locking or transactions for this simple interaction. Am I right on this?
Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the prime consideration to take into account is a scenario where multiple workers retrieve the same row.

The UPDATE and SELECT operations themselves should be fine, but if you have multiple workers consuming via SELECT on the same table, then you might get two workers simultaneously processing the same row.

If each worker is required to process separate rows, locking on SELECT may be required with careful consideration of deadlock if there's a significant unit of work associated with your process.